# Running Angular7 app without using server

Tags: angular, angular-ui-router, web-frontend

Guys, I'm just testing the angular app without the server for specific reasons. With server its working fine.

I build my angular app using `ng build --prod`. I went to the dist folder and open my index.html

then my header and footer are loading but the main content is not loading (all the required js/css files are loaded).

the main content configured as load through route in the routing module. The component pointed to the route is not loading.

**app.comonent.html**

```
<app-header></app-header>
<router-outlet></router-outlet>
<app-footer></app-footer>
```

**app-routing.module.ts**

```
const routes: Routes =  [
  {path: '', redirectTo: '/test', pathMatch: 'full'},
  {path: 'test', component: TestComponent, canActivate: [TestService]},
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(routes)],
  exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class AppRoutingModule { }
```

Is there any way to load components pointed to route without using the server. In the above mentioned TestService also I'm not making HTTP calls.

Thanks

Comment: No, you can't. Resources like JS need to get properly loaded into a browser for execution via HTTP

Comment: Any errors in the Browser's console?

Answer (score 0):

If you're not making any HTTP calls, then it should work.

Edit **tsconfig.json** and change the `module` property to `CommonJS` for example. Unlike regular scripts, ES6 modules are subject to [same-origin](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Security/Same-origin_policy) policy.

Then, try to build the app like this `ng build --base-href ./`